# Constructing an orthogonal rotation transforming a basis vector into the equal sum

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

Could anyone please help me to construct an orthogonal matrix which would rotate the first basis vector $v_1$ from an orthonormal set $\{v_k\}_{k=1}^N$ into a vector having equal projections on all the basis vectors?
$$
U v_1 = v_\Sigma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k=1}^N v_k
$$
I'm looking for the simplest possible rotation, the one which would go in the $(v_1,v_\Sigma)$ plane, without any additional extra rotations around $v_1$ or $v_\Sigma$.

Right away I can tell that
$$
O_N = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\end{pmatrix} \ .
$$

How do I proceed further?

**UPDATE**

So the answer turns out to be:
$$
O_N = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & \cdots & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & a & b & b & \cdots & b\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & b & a & b & \cdots & b\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & b & b & a & \cdots & b\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \ddots & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & a\\
\end{pmatrix} \ ,
$$
where
$$
a = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{N+\sqrt{N}-1}} \ , \quad
b = - \dfrac{1}{N + \sqrt{N}}
$$
(The answer was obtained in a brute-force way, using Mathematica's functions `RotationMatrix[]` and `FindSequenceFunction[]`.)

Comment: You can do Gram-Schmidt for the basis $v_\Sigma, v_1,v_2,\dots, v_{n-1}$, write the rotation in the obtained orthonormal basis, and apply basis transformation to get the matrix in the original basis.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow the simplest possible rotation criterion.  I assume this is an n-dimensional space.  Here's a very easy solution:

consider the image of U on the entire orthonormal set / unitary matrix

$ \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
U\mathbf v_1  & U\mathbf v_2  & \cdots & U\mathbf v_n 
\end{array}\bigg]  = U V = V Q$

now select $Q$ to be the Discerete Fourier Transform, so
$U:=VQV^*$
gives a solution

note in particular
$UV\mathbf e_1 = U\mathbf v_1 = VQ\mathbf e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}V\mathbf 1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf v_k$

Comment: Cool! I don't think it's the 'simplest' one but definitely a beautiful solution!